# Can't start appmon in erlang R17 RC1

Tags: erlang

I have Erlang/OTP 17 [RELEASE CANDIDATE 1] installed and i can't start appmon. I have tried:

```
appmon:start().
** exception error: undefined function appmon:start/0
```

I also tried:

```
l(appmon).
```

And I get the following error:

```
{error,nofile}
```

How can I make appmon work ?

Comment: The following applications were removed: `appmon`, `pman`, `toolbar`, `tv`. The `ose` application was added.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`appmon` looks to have been removed, in favour of the new `observer` application. See the note [here](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_17.0-rc1.readme). There seems to be precious little online documentation on why, but presumably the docs included in your erlang installation would at least help you find how to use it.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in [sanmiguel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24/sanmiguel), `appmon` has been removed.

The solution for me was to use this command instead:

```
observer:start().
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, **appmon** has been removed starting from R17 along with the **gs** framework. It is replaced by **observer** which uses wxWidgets as GUI framework.

In my case where I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial), I need to install **libwxgtk3.0-dev** which will install any required additional packages. Running 'wx-config --version' gave me the hints on which package to install.

```
$ wx-config --version
The program 'wx-config' can be found in the following packages:
 * libwxbase3.0-dev
 * libwxgtk3.0-dev
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```